# RNN for Structural Time Series Model?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I am thinking about exploring the RNN model structure for structural time series. to be more specific, let say my output (target) is a group of variables:

*X(1,t) X(2,t), ...X(n,t)*

and I believe that there are some Endogenous Effects within this group, which makes a dynamic structural model desirable.

my idea now is to build a RNN model on this, with the inputs as:

*X(1,t-1) X(1,t-2), ...X(1,t-k), X(2,t-1), ...X(n,t-k)*

here I am assuming that only historical information up to previous k periods would be useful.

my question is:

1. is the setup appropriate for this kind of question?
2. is there any available RNN framework for such a setup (Tensorflow, Keras)? more specifically, can I specify the residual/error based on the entire group (X1-Xn), instead of Xi individually?

thanks!